# Ajax call always calls success response function

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

I want to return two different jsp pages from struts.xml using ajax call based on 'success' or 'failure'.

my ajax method is :

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  success: function(data) { 
        $('#page-area').html("");   
        $('#page-area').html(data);             
        $('#modal_new-pack').modal('show');     
  },
  failure: function(data) { 
        $('#page-area').html("");   
        $('#page-area').html(data);             
  },
  cache: false
});
```

My struts.xml is :

```
<action name="modify" class="com.test.ennt.action.CorporateAction"
            method="modify">
    <result name="success">/jsp/VF_ManageSuccess.jsp</result>
    <result name="failure">/jsp/VF_ManageError.jsp</result>
</action>
```

and the action method is :

```
public String modify() {
        corporate = corporateManager.getCorporate(getCorporateID());
        if (corporate == null) {
            return "failure";
        }
        this.disable = "true";
        return "success";
    }
```

based on the return value from my action method and struts.xml failure/success result I need to show my jsp page.
But the ajax always runs the 'success' response function.

Comment: FYI fail key word is not not `failure`, it is `error`

Comment: Your function returns either failure or success. In both cases, it's actually returning something. That means, if it's returning something, then the ajax call is a successful one. The failures keyword in the ajax call holds true, when the ajax call isn't successful, which happens when the called function (modify()) isn't available, or network connectivity error. By the way, are you Oriya? @rojalinbiswal

Comment: Giving you an upvote. This question will help others to have their confusions cleared.

Comment: Yes, that's true, the error is returned when ajax call fails.

Comment: I've removed my answer as I don't know struts well enough. Simply open your web console, run your code, and look at what the response you get back is. That should tell you what to look for in the `success` callback (and it will show you the HTTP response code, which if it's 200 is a successful response and will call the `success` handler; if not, it will trigger a call to the `error` (not `failure`) handler).

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong, the message that are you back in response both will jump into success method.

You can do with the result.

Eg:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  success: function(data) { 
     if(data=="success"){
        $('#page-area').html("");   
        $('#page-area').html(data);             
        $('#modal_new-pack').modal('show');   
     }
     else
     {
        $('#page-area').html("");   
        $('#page-area').html(data);
     }  
  }
  cache: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When there is an error occur in the server, error function is called. Not depending on the value you've returned.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  success: function(data) { 
      if($.trim(data) === 'success'){
            $('#page-area').html("");   
            $('#page-area').html(data);             
            $('#modal_new-pack').modal('show');     
      } else {
            $('#page-area').html("");   
            $('#page-area').html(data);
      }
  },
  error: function() { 
      alert('Error')
  },
  cache: false
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. But my $.trim(data) is the jsp page content how can it be same as 'success' it will never same. I checked with data.success but that will come as undefined or success

Comment: @rojalinbiswal hi, did you try alert/console.log for data?

Comment: yes i have tried i its my jsp page content. So do I need to change the result type in struts.xml

Answer (score 0):

in $.ajax failure really means http error status

- HTTP Status Codes 100-101 - Informational Status Codes
- HTTP Status Codes 200-206 - Successful Status Codes
- HTTP Status Codes 300-307 - Redirection Status Codes
- HTTP Status Codes 400-416 - Client Error Status Codes
- HTTP Status Codes 500-505 - Server Error Status Codes

I think the two jsp VF_ManageSuccess.jsp and VF_ManageError.jsp are both return http status code 200;